# Apache Echarts & Vue-ECharts - Pie charts animation not working on load

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2, echarts, apache-echarts

I have a simple doughnut/pie chart that is working fine, but I can not get the default animation, or any animation to work.

I'm using laravel 8, vuejs 2, and echarts / vue-echarts.

**This is my vue component in /resopurces/js/components/popular-brands-chart.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-chart class="chart" :option="option" autoresize />
</template>

<script>
import { use } from "echarts/core";
import { CanvasRenderer } from "echarts/renderers";
import { PieChart } from "echarts/charts";
import { TitleComponent, TooltipComponent, LegendComponent } from "echarts/components";
import VChart from "vue-echarts";

use([CanvasRenderer, PieChart, TitleComponent, TooltipComponent, LegendComponent]);

export default {
  name: "mostpopularbrands",
  components: {
    VChart,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      option: {
        animation: true,
        backgroundColor: "#fefefe",
        color: ["#AD5BA3", "#4EC0B1", "#F4A620", "#EE5969", "#528DCA"],
        textStyle: {
          fontFamily: "museo-sans",
          fontWeight: "bold",
        },
        label: {
          show: true,
          color: "#fff",
        },
        tooltip: {
          trigger: "item",
          formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)",
        },
        legend: {
          orient: "vertical",
          right: "15%",
          top: "13%",
          data: ["Titleist", "TaylorMade", "Callaway", "Ping", "Nike"],
          icon: "circle",
          padding: [5, 5],
          itemGap: 15,
          textStyle: {
            fontFamily: "museo-sans",
            fontWeight: "normal",
            color: "#4C4C4C",
            fontSize: "15",
          },
        },
        series: [
          {
            name: "Most popular brands",
            type: "pie",
            animationType: "expansion",
            animationDuration: 5000,
            animationDurationUpdate: 500,
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360,
            radius: [30, 95],
            center: ["25%", "36%"],
            label: {
              formatter: function (d = "{d}") {
                let rounderPercent = Math.round(d.percent);
                return rounderPercent + "%";
              },
              position: "inside",
              show: true,
            },
            data: [
              { value: 170, name: "Titleist" },
              { value: 100, name: "TaylorMade" },
              { value: 75, name: "Callaway" },
              { value: 50, name: "Ping" },
              { value: 37, name: "Nike" },
            ],
            itemStyle: {
              borderColor: "#fff",
              borderWidth: 2,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.chart {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

**In the bootstrap.js** file I have added this also but pretty sure it's not doing anything at the moment, and even when I did import it using the vue 3 examples nothing worked.

```
/* VueCompositionAPI */
import VueCompositionAPI from '@vue/composition-api'
Vue.use(VueCompositionAPI)
```

Technically, I should not have to do anything to get this to animate, no console errors. Here is a reference of what it should do :
https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=pie-doughnut

I can actually get this working via the CDN and codepen here, why it works, I have no clue :
https://codepen.io/marcgaumont/pen/OJWyZwe

This is the package used for vue:
https://github.com/ecomfe/vue-echarts

Everything works fine, but after 10 + hours trying to get this to animate, trying every example there is. I'm totally out of luck.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I have a similar issue. I followed the example here: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-animation-delay though

Comment: I still can not get any animation what so ever to work, maybe it has something to do with how laravel implies us to use .vue files, maybe im not importing something. From my example above, you can see on CDN it animates, why using import packages it does not.